# Correct Passportjs strategy to use (hash vs jwt)

Tags: node.js, authentication, passport.js

I have a Laravel app which I'm trying to convert to NodeJS. In the original app we have an API for which access is protected by random generated tokens - assigned to each user and stored in our DB. We automatically generate this secret token when a user first registers then they use it for as long as they would like to use our services. (We verify subscription details for users using these tokens).

I'm trying to replicate the same on NodeJS but I'm a bit lost about the right authentication strategy to use, as passportJS has JSON Web Tokens (JWT) and 'hash'. They both seem correct but I can't figure out the difference and which would be most appropriate in this case.

If hash is the correct strategy would I have to use JWT to generate the token and assign it to each user? Probably I haven't understood properly the concept of hashes and token for authentications. What are the differences between hashes and token for authentication purposes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did some more research and found out that the JWT are not exactly what we were using or what we need for our app. We simply create SHA hashes for each user based on personal details and a secret key. This hash is now created and used in the new application correctly. It was simpler than I thought. And for those wanting to learn a bit more about JWT, this Medium article could help a lot:

https://medium.com/vandium-software/5-easy-steps-to-understanding-json-web-tokens-jwt-1164c0adfcec